# Report Builder 3.0 - How to sum output of expression

Tags: sum, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

We are looking to sum the output of an expression meaning that it does not exist as a field. Is there a way that that we can sum the content of a range of tablix cells?

[image: We are looking to display a sum of output of <<Expr>>]

In the above screen capture i am looking to have the total of <<"Expr">> displayed in the Total column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to provide an expression that computes the total directly. You can only reference the contents of cells (using the ReportItems collection) that have scope "higher" than the current scope. In other words, you can reference a total text box in a non-total tablix cell, but you cannot reference a non-total tablix cell in a total text box.